# Autoactualizar hora PDA windows ce via wifi

Tags: c#, windowsce

Este es mi primer post, la verdad no soy muy fan de preguntar por internet, pero en este caso no soy capaz de avanzar hacia ningún lado, y la verdad la ayuda de foros no me ayuda demasiado.

Os cuento, estoy desarrollando una aplicación para PDAs que utilizan

```
Windows CE, en la info de la pda puedo ver esto: 

Windows Mobile 6.5 Professional

CE OS 5.2.23121 Build( 23121.5.3.6)
```

Y mi idea, es que en la tienda cuando las pdas que utilizamos se quedan sin bateria, o se apagan, se desconfigura la hora( Ya se que es por culpa de la pila interna que esta agotada) pero tampoco tenemos presupuesto para cambiarlas y se me ocurrio desarrollar una app, que actualice la hora automaticamente a traves de internet (en este caso las pdas tienen wifi todo el dia)

Averigue que necesitaba VS2008 instale todo lo necesarioy  manos a la obra, he conseguido hacer una app muy sencillita, pero cuando trato de hacer la hora, me da errores, y tampoco se muy bien si es lo que necesito hacer.

Alguien me podria indicar los pasos a seguir o los complementos o librerias que necesito para realizar esto? Me ahorraria muchisimos problemas en procesos de guardado de informacion en el servidor.

Aqui os dejo mi "codigo":

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UpdateTime
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_ParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetTime();
        }

        private struct SYSTEMTIME
        {
            public short year;
            public short month;
            public short dayOfWeek;
            public short day;
            public short hour;
            public short minute;
            public short second;
            public short milliseconds;
        }
        // Compiling for Windows Mobile
        [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
        static extern bool SetLocalTime(ref SYSTEMTIME time);

        public void SetTime()
        {
            SYSTEMTIME st;

            // Thanks to Jim Hollenhorst <hollenho@attbi.com>
            DateTime trts = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(LocalClockOffset);

            st.year = (short)trts.Year;
            st.month = (short)trts.Month;
            st.dayOfWeek = (short)trts.DayOfWeek;
            st.day = (short)trts.Day;
            st.hour = (short)trts.Hour;
            st.minute = (short)trts.Minute;
            st.second = (short)trts.Second;
            st.milliseconds = (short)trts.Millisecond;

            SetLocalTime(ref st);
            label2.Text = "Hora actualizada";
        }
    }
}
```

Y el error que me tira al darle al play:

```
------ Operación Generar iniciada: proyecto: UpdateTime, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;PocketPC /win32res:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SDK\v3.5\Bin\HiDPI.res" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\UpdateTime.exe /resource:obj\Debug\UpdateTime.Form1.resources /resource:obj\Debug\UpdateTime.Properties.Resources.resources /target:winexe Form1.cs Form1.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs
C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\UpdateTime\UpdateTime\Form1.cs(42,28): advertencia CS0626: El método, operador o descriptor de acceso 'UpdateTime.Form1.SetLocalTime(ref UpdateTime.Form1.SYSTEMTIME)' está marcado como externo y no tiene atributos. Agregue un atributo DllImport para especificar la implementación externa.
C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\UpdateTime\UpdateTime\Form1.cs(49,58): error CS0103: El nombre 'LocalClockOffset' no existe en el contexto actual

Compilación completada -- 1 errores, 1 advertencias
========== Generar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
========== Implementar: 0 correctos, 0 incorrectos, 0 omitidos ==========
```

---

Dejo el error con saltos de línea para mejor visualización:

```
------ Operación Generar iniciada: proyecto: UpdateTime, configuración: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt 
/warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE;PocketPC 
/win32res:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\SDK\v3.5\Bin\HiDPI.res" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\mscorlib.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Core.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Data.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Drawing.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Windows.Forms.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Xml.dll" 
/reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
/debug+ /debug:full /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\UpdateTime.exe 
/resource:obj\Debug\UpdateTime.Form1.resources /resource:obj\Debug\UpdateTime.Properties.Resources.resources 
/target:winexe Form1.cs Form1.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs


C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\UpdateTime\UpdateTime\Form1.cs(42,28): 
advertencia CS0626: El método, operador o descriptor de acceso 'UpdateTime.Form1.SetLocalTime(ref UpdateTime.Form1.SYSTEMTIME)' 
está marcado como externo y no tiene atributos. Agregue un atributo DllImport para especificar la implementación externa.


C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\UpdateTime\UpdateTime\Form1.cs(49,58): 
error CS0103: El nombre 'LocalClockOffset' no existe en el contexto actual

Compilación completada -- 1 errores, 1 advertencias
========== Generar: 0 correctos, 1 incorrectos, 0 actualizados, 0 omitidos ==========
========== Implementar: 0 correctos, 0 incorrectos, 0 omitidos ==========
```

EDITO: 
Me decia el usuario drielnox que probara a hacerlo mediante el registro de la propia pda; hice el snapshot como decia en el link que me paso y he comparado los dos snaps; efectivamente si cambio la hora veo la difeencia que pasa a estar asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero veo que simplemente cambia de 1 a 0 en los registros correspondientes a la hora, pero eso no quita que vuelva a funcionar, realmente eso estaba activado y aunque lo desactive y active de nuevo, sigue sin cambiar la hora.

Muchas gracias anticipado.

Saludos a todos.

Comment: Disculpa, ¿probaste configurando que se actualice la hora automáticamente en el sistema operativo? Según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862303/3817681) y [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19548902/3817681) de SOen, podrías realizarlo sin la necesidad de programar ni una sola linea de código. Agrego, ademas, que para que estas soluciones anteriores funcionen, posiblemente tengas que configurar el router (aunque lo dudo).

Comment: Si, fue lo primero que probe y da igual lo que hagas, que la hora no la actualiza hay que ponersela manual, y con la pila interna agotada cada vez que se apaga pierde la hora.

Comment: Intentaste modificando los registros donde está esta configuracion de WinCE?

Comment: No se de que registros me hablas, ni vi ningun lado donde me dijeran nada de eso, si asi pudiera solucionarlo tambien me serviria

Comment: Justo estaba viendolo, y la verdad ahora mi duda es, tengo que instalar esa aplicacion en la pda para acceder al registro de la misma y cambiar los valores que me dicen en ese post no?

Comment: Técnicamente, si. Lo que dice es que instales esa app, saques un _snapshot_ del registry cuando la pda inicia y luego, otro snap cuando cambias la configuracion de la "hora automática" para que puedas fijar el valor en cada inicio de sistema operativo.

Comment: Edito mi pregunta @drielnox

Answer (score 1):

puedes usar la API de OpenNETCF, descarga desde https://opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx

Luego utiliza el OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.dll desde tu código y le transfieres la nueva fecha:

```
OpenNETCF.WindowsCE.DateTimeHelper.SystemTime = new DateTime(2019, 01, 30, 15, 45, 00);
```

Te tendría que funcionar perfectamente.

Comment: Pero de esta manera tendria que establecer yo la hora siempre no? La idea es que se autoactualize comprobando con los servidores de microsoft( porque me imagino que otros no tendra) y que actualice la hora, gracias por tu respuesta. Ademas el link no me funciona :/

Comment: Sí claro, si se conecta con tu server, que la lea de ahí y se lo pasas al DateTime(), desde una db, un XLM, un Jason... si no, haces una clase que lea directamente la hora cualquier NTP, por ejemplo hora.es  y listo, para insertarlo en el DateTime()

Comment: Lo he de probar al terminar de comprobar si las aplicaciones que ya hay me sirven o no, muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes, tu código está tirando dos errores:

El primero,

```
C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\UpdateTime\UpdateTime\Form1.cs(42,28): advertencia CS0626: El método, operador o descriptor de acceso 'UpdateTime.Form1.SetLocalTime(ref UpdateTime.Form1.SYSTEMTIME)' está marcado como externo y no tiene atributos. Agregue un atributo DllImport para especificar la implementación externa.
```

hace referencia a algún problema al momento de importar la función **SetLocalTime**, específicamente dice que no la puede encontrar en ninguna de las librerías importadas.

Si revisamos los imports que realizás, únicamente enlazás con la librería *coredll.dll* que por lo visto no tiene la función que necesitás. Buscando en la MSDN, parece que tenés que enlazar con *kernel32.dll*.

---

El segundo error,

```
C:\Users\david\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\UpdateTime\UpdateTime\Form1.cs(49,58): error CS0103: El nombre 'LocalClockOffset' no existe en el contexto actual
```

dice que no tenés ninguna variable llamada LocalClockOffset declarada en tu programa.

Busqué el código original y esa variable está declarada de la siguiente forma:

```
    public int LocalClockOffset
    {
        get
        {
            // Thanks to DNH <dnharris@csrlink.net>
            TimeSpan span = (ReceiveTimestamp - OriginateTimestamp) + (TransmitTimestamp - DestinationTimestamp);
            return (int)(span.TotalMilliseconds / 2);
        }
    }
```

Podrías hacer copy paste de esto y de las dependencias de lo mismo pero te recomendaría reemplazar la variable con el valor que necesitas. Al final de cuentas esta variable es un integer que almacena la cantidad de milisegundos de offset entre el tiempo devuelto por DateTime.Now y la hora que querés obtener.

---

Luego, algo que no es un error de código sino de la lógica detrás del programa, con este código lo único que hacés es obtener la hora del sistema, agregarle un offset y actualizar la hora del sistema. A menos que el sistema tenga la hora correcta o sepas con seguridad cual es la diferencia que se produce no te va a servir para hacer lo que querés.

---

Finalmente, lo que te recomendaría hacer es utilizar alguna aplicación que haga la sincronización por vos. Busqué en XDA y encontré varias, te dejo dos cuyas descargas todavía están vigentes:

- TimeSyncTZ 0-06: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=383792
- Time Synchronization: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=659582

La que más parece ajustarse a tus necesidades es la primera ya que permite su ejecución desde la línea de comandos con lo que agregandola a HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Init te podés asegurar que se ejecuta cada vez que se reinicia el equipo. Si esta opción no te sirve en este archivo podés encontrar otras: https://portal.siriusware.com/docs/kb-pdf/Hardware-related/scanning_2009_july_17_4.pdf

Lamentablemente no encuentro mi Motorola por ningún lado para hacer pruebas así que no pude testear ninguno de los programas. Espero que te sirva...

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, he probado las 2 aplicaciones, la primera como bien decías es la buena, me ha sincronizado la hora perfectamente, pero el problema es que hay que seleccionar servidor para sincronizar y darle a start digamos, voy a intentar hacer las correcciones en mi programa a ver si soy capaz de hacer que actualice solo y te digo algo.

Comment: Fijate en la sección **Usage (command line)** cómo usarla llamandola desde la línea de comandos. Sería algo así: *TimeSyncTZ.exe silent /server:ntp.servidor.com*, donde ntp.servidor.com sería el servidor elegido.

Comment: Como desde la linea de comandos? la PDA tiene cmd? por lo que leo en el ussage con hacer el shortcut en donde arranca los programas y definirle los parametros en el nombre deberia ser suficiente, te refieres a eso por casualidad?

Comment: Algo parecido, me refería la opción Run/Ejecutar que te permitía correr programas, similar a la de los Windows de escritorio. Igual tu idea es buena, crear un acceso directo y copiarlo a *\Windows\Start Menu* para asegurarse que se ejecuta cuando se reinicia el equipo logra lo mismo y más fácil...

Comment: He probado añadiendo el shortcut y lo lanza pero no lo hace automático, también he probado a añadir en el registro "" TimeSyncTZ.exe silent /server:time-a.nist.gov "" (en este caso ya que es el servidor que me funciona), la verdad ya no se me ocurre mucho mas donde poder meter esos comandos x.x gracias por todo

Comment: La otra que veo es creando un archivo .run en la carpeta *\Application\Startup* como indica en el pdf que te pasé al final de la página 7

Comment: He hecho el TimeSyncTZ.run con estas lineas: "\Program Files\DaveShaw\TimeSyncTZ.exe
"
silent /server:time-a.nist.gov
Pero me dice que no existe ninguna aplicacion con el nombre del .run que cree, no se que deberia hacer, si quieres hablamos por chat

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89053/discussion-between-peisou-and-roberto-vaccaro).